# Выборка данных из 3 SQL таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

В двух словах, есть 3 таблицы в БД:

1. Cписок всех игроков
2. Cписок имён этих игроков (отдельно, потому что здесь все данные об аккаунтах)
3. Cписок друзей (кто кого добавил в друзья в игре)

Мне нужно достать имена из 2 таблицы (колонка `firstname`), количество опыта из 1 таблицы (колонка `exp`) и проверить чтобы id игрока было в 3 таблице (в колонке `user1` или `user2`).

Мой запрос:

```
SELECT
f.exp AS Exp,
u.firstname AS Name
FROM farmer f
JOIN customer u ON f.userId = u.customer_id
JOIN friendship fr ON fr.user1 = 33 OR fr.user2 = 33
ORDER BY (f.exp) DESC
```

Он работает, но получаются дубли. Что я сделал не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ответ**:

В итоге у меня получился вот такой запрос. Это выборка списка друзей и тех кто добавляется в друзья к игроку, которая берется из трёх таблиц.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
userId as id,
exp,
oc_customer.firstname as name,
CONCAT(IFNULL(fr1.question,''),IFNULL(fr2.question,'')) as status,
CONCAT(IFNULL(fr1.user2,''),IFNULL(fr2.user2,'')) as inviter
FROM farmer
LEFT JOIN oc_customer ON customer_id=userId
LEFT JOIN friendship as fr1 ON fr1.user1='$userId'
AND (fr1.question=2 OR fr1.question=1) AND fr1.user2=userId
LEFT JOIN friendship as fr2 ON fr2.user1=userId
AND (fr2.question=2 OR fr2.question=1)AND fr2.user2='$userId'
WHERE userId!='$userId'
AND ((fr1.question=2 OR fr1.question=1) OR (fr2.question=2 OR fr2.question=1))
ORDER BY (exp)
DESC
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

status - **2** (друг), status - **1** (запрос в друзья), **inviter** (тот кто отправил запрос)

Comment: Смотрите в сторону JOIN'ах  
https://anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-join/

Comment: @Артур, спасибо, написал запрос, но нужно его доделать, а то выводит дубли. Может вы знаете в чем проблема?

Comment: попробуй `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: @IgorNikolaev, спасибо, работает!

Comment: @Abmin тогда оформлю, как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить уникальные значения, следует использовать `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Из документации:

> The ALL and DISTINCT modifiers specify whether duplicate rows should be returned. ALL (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be returned, including duplicates. DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set. It is an error to specify both modifiers. DISTINCTROW is a synonym for DISTINCT.

Это значит, что если использовать `SELECT` без указания `DISTINCT` или `DISTINCTROW`, то будет использоваться модификатор `ALL` и будут выданы все совпадающие записи.

[Ссылка](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) на документацию.